# Cannot assign a value of type '[NSObject : AnyObject]' to a value of type '[String : AnyObject]!'

Tags: swift, firebase

I am getting this error from the FireBase ios-swift-chat-example.

[image: where the issue lies]

Comment: Try this line 

    `let attributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:cell.textView!.tintColor,NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName:1]
    cell.textView!.textView.linkTextAttributes = attributes`

Comment: So this got rid of the error message: let attributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:cell.textView!.tintColor, NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: 1] cell.textView!.linkTextAttributes = attributes (Without the extra textView in cell.textView!) That being said, would you mind explaining what was wrong here and how using this at least passes the syntax checking? Thanks again! @EGHM

Comment: I think you mean to thank @Dev I only edited your post to inline the image.

Comment: @EddiePratt, I posted the answers with explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While assigning the dictionary to constant variable, you don't required to type cast because you are already creating dictionary of type `[String : AnyObject]` which required for assignment to the `UITextView.linkTextAttributes`.

```
let attributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:cell.textView!.tintColor,NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName:1]
cell.textView!.textView.linkTextAttributes = attributes
```

Comment: For Swift 2         
```let attributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:cell.textView!.tintColor,NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName:1]

cell.textView!.linkTextAttributes = attributes```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you are dealing with string or dictionary. In  my case i handled dictionary as string.